# Cannot connect to URL ms-word URL scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsurl, url-scheme

I'm sending users to the Microsoft Word app to edit a document. To do this I'm using a URL scheme that I have whitelisted in my `info.plist` as "ms-word". All of the questions and answers I've read about this are `outdated/involve` solutions that I've tried multiple times.

Before you say "just use `UIDocumentInteractionController`", that doc controller doesn't allow for editing the same file and it cannot send the user back to the original application after viewing the document.

Here's what I've tried in Objective - C

```
NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"ms-word:ofe|u|https://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/pubform.doc" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSUTF8StringEncoding)]];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:ourURL] ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:ourURL];
}
```

I've also tried variations of this such as removing the encoding and manually encoding the pipes as %7C because that is what the end result looks like after encoding. This variation was used in a tutorial that I saw [here](https://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/02/16/opening-a-document-with-office-mobile-from-your-own-application/).

Here's another [tutorial](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/officewopi/en/latest/scenarios/from_app.html) I looked at that didn't work for me.

I've also tried other public facing word documents I found on google by searching by file type `.doc/.docx`, none worked.

Here's what I've tried in Swift

```
let ourURL = NSURL(string: ("ms-word:ofe|u|http://www.fcu.edu.tw/wSite/public/Attachment/f1355389313906.doc").stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)!
        print(ourURL)
        let ourApplication:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        if(ourApplication.canOpenURL(ourURL)) {
            ourApplication.openURL(ourURL)
        }
```

Again I've tried multiple variations, different encodings, `NSUTF8, stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingAllowedCharacters(NSCharacters.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())`, as well as different word document urls...

I've also tried downloading a document's `NSData` and writing it locally to a file directory within my phone, then opening that file, but the `URL` Scheme doesn't support local directories (`UIDocumentInteractionController` does support this, but again, you can't edit that copy nor return the user to their application).

There is [little documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn911482.aspx#sectionSection1) about ms word's url schemes, and I've done plenty of research on the topic and it seems there are many people still stuck with the same issue and have gone to [Microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365legacy-mso_mobaccess/ios-how-to-open-word-app-via-uri-scheme-with-a/c061f306-6062-4571-9561-114987c4f352) and other help forums with no solutions since those forums are populated with people who do not have experience in this specific field.

Every attempt at this has resulted in either:

1) Word successfully launching, but then I receive this error: "Cannot connect to `URL`, use a valid `URL`"

2) Word successfully launching, but then I receive the same error and then after dismissing the error I see something like "word cannot open the file at url "

Comment: The `ourURL` is `nil` in my testing.

Comment: I think you need to encode the url first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that I keep getting this error because it is simply **not possible**.

For the ms-word url scheme to work, the document must live in SharePoint or OneDrive, stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn911482.aspx#sectionSection1).

> You can enable users who are running Office on an iOS device to open and edit **files stored in SharePoint or OneDrive** from any application, and then quickly return them to the original application when they’re done editing the file.

Comment: But how dropbox and box.com does it in their iOS apps?

Comment: @Konstantin You found the solution? I have the same question here.